# Wordpress Theme Positioning

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Iam trying to manually position my social media icons to the right under my main menu . It seems my media queries doesnt work correctly . Iam the html code with my css and couple of screenshots to so you can understand .

[image]

And my CSS code is :

```
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1224px) {
    div.header_mid_inner {
        position: relative;
    }

    div.header_mid_inner .social_wrap {
        position: absolute;
            left: 91%;
        top: 50%;

    }
}
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1824px) {
    div.header_mid_inner {
        position: relative;
    }

    div.header_mid_inner .social_wrap {
        position: absolute;
            left: 95%;
        top: 40%;

    }
}
```

It seems when the screen is getting bigger or smaller they are off .. is there anything i can do to fix that ?

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get a proper start for an answer for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `left: 9X%`, trying using `right: 0%`. If the `<div>` is wrapped properly, should work fine.